# How to repeat the steps

Tags: python, loops

In my program I have total of 3 steps.

1. To find the mean
2. Split the given list using the mean value
3. If the threshold value > epsilon then update mean value and repeat the step 2 again with updated mean value, else finished.

I have achieved above two steps anyhow. Third step I have achieved only half and struggling in how to repeat the step 2 till the threshold value will be less than epsilon.

My code is below:

```py
import numpy as np
store_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1]

# Step 1
mean_value = np.mean(store_list)
print("Mean Value : " + str(mean_value))

# Step 2
small_list = [i for i in store_list if i <= mean_value]
big_list = [i for i in store_list if i > mean_value]
print(small_list)
print(big_list)

toe_1 = np.mean(small_list)
toe_2 = np.mean(big_list)
print("toe value 1 : " + str(toe_1))
print("toe value 2 : " + str(toe_2))

toe_sum = np.sum([toe_1, toe_2])
toe_cap = np.divide(toe_sum, 2)
print("toe cap : " + str(toe_cap))

# Step 3
new_threshold = np.subtract(mean_value, toe_cap)
print(new_threshold)
epsilon_value = 0.1
if new_threshold > epsilon_value:
    mean_value = toe_cap
    print("new mean : " + str(mean_value))
```

My output of above is:

```
Mean Value : 1.8571428571428572
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 3]
toe value 1 : 1.0
toe value 2 : 2.5
toe cap : 1.75
new threshold : 0.1071428571428572
new mean : 1.75
```

In this case I have to repeat the step 2 again considering new mean. I am new to Python.

Comment: Have you explored the looping constructs in python?

Comment: @quamrana : Yes I have explored but in this case I am not able to make the repeat loop.

Comment: Which looping constructs have you tried. Did anything work, or did something not work that you can ask a question about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to numpy but i can imagine that all you need is a recursive runner function, i don't want to break the structure of your code, therefore i did not try to optimize the code. You can try the following code, i tried, it works:

```
import numpy as np


def step2(store_list, mean_value):
    small_list = [i for i in store_list if i <= mean_value]
    big_list = [i for i in store_list if i > mean_value]
    toe_1 = np.mean(small_list)
    toe_2 = np.mean(big_list)
    toe_sum = np.sum([toe_1, toe_2])
    toe_cap = np.divide(toe_sum, 2)
    return small_list, big_list, toe_1, toe_2, toe_cap


def step3(mean_value, toe_cap):
    new_threshold = np.subtract(mean_value, toe_cap)
    print(new_threshold)
    epsilon_value = 0.1
    if new_threshold > epsilon_value:
        return True, toe_cap
    else:
        return False, mean_value


def my_run(store_list, mean_value):
    small_list, big_list, toe_1, toe_2, toe_cap = step2(store_list, mean_value)
    print(small_list)
    print(big_list)
    print("toe value 1 : " + str(toe_1))
    print("toe value 2 : " + str(toe_2))
    print("toe cap : " + str(toe_cap))
    condition, mean_value = step3(mean_value, toe_cap)
    if condition:
        print("new mean : " + str(mean_value))
        my_run(store_list, mean_value)


def main():
    store_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
    mean_value = np.mean(store_list)
    print("Mean Value : " + str(mean_value))
    my_run(store_list, mean_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of loops in python. `for` loops and `while` loops. You can achieve a "loop" by doing recursion which is just calling a function inside the same function, having a correct exit statement, like this:

```py
def print_10_times(num, count=0):
    if count < 10:
        print(num)
        count += 1
        print_10_times(num, count)

print_10_times(5)  # will print '5' 10 times
```

Although there are easier ways to do loops in python. The easiest loop to do when you know how many loops you will need to do beforehand, is the `for` loop. The above example could be executed like this:

```py
def print_10_times(num):
    for i in range(10):
        print(num)

print_10_times(5)  # will print '5' 10 times
```

The other loop you can do is the `while` loop. To use it you will have to have a correct exit statement in the beggining of it. If you wanted to execute the above example with a while loop it would have to look something like this:

```py
def print_10_times(num):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        print(num)

print_10_times(5)  # will print '5' 10 times
```

For you code to work you will need to have an exit statement for every loop you'd want to use. For example maybe you wanted those 3 steps to run 2 times. You could do this:

```py
import numpy as np

store_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1]

for i in range(2):
    # Step 1
    mean_value = np.mean(store_list)
    print("Mean Value : " + str(mean_value))

    # Step 2
    small_list = [i for i in store_list if i <= mean_value]
    big_list = [i for i in store_list if i > mean_value]
    print(small_list)
    print(big_list)

    toe_1 = np.mean(small_list)
    toe_2 = np.mean(big_list)
    print("toe value 1 : " + str(toe_1))
    print("toe value 2 : " + str(toe_2))

    toe_sum = np.sum([toe_1, toe_2])
    toe_cap = np.divide(toe_sum, 2)
    print("toe cap : " + str(toe_cap))

    # Step 3
    new_threshold = np.subtract(mean_value, toe_cap)
    print(new_threshold)
    epsilon_value = 0.1
    if new_threshold > epsilon_value:
        mean_value = toe_cap
        print("new mean : " + str(mean_value))
```

But this will output the same thing 2 times.

> I have achieved above two steps anyhow. Third step I have achieved only half and struggling in how to repeat the step 2 till the threshold value will be less than epsilon.

You can do this with a simple while loop:

```py
import numpy as np

store_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1]

# Step 1
mean_value = np.mean(store_list)
print("Mean Value : " + str(mean_value))

# Step 2
toe_cap = 3
e = np.exp(1)
while toe_cap > e:
    small_list = [i for i in store_list if i <= mean_value]
    big_list = [i for i in store_list if i > mean_value]
    print(small_list)
    print(big_list)

    toe_1 = np.mean(small_list)
    toe_2 = np.mean(big_list)
    print("toe value 1 : " + str(toe_1))
    print("toe value 2 : " + str(toe_2))

    toe_sum = np.sum([toe_1, toe_2])
    toe_cap = np.divide(toe_sum, 2)
    print("toe cap : " + str(toe_cap))

# Step 3
new_threshold = np.subtract(mean_value, toe_cap)
print(new_threshold)
epsilon_value = 0.1
if new_threshold > epsilon_value:
    mean_value = toe_cap
    print("new mean : " + str(mean_value))
```

This loop will end when `toe_cap` is smaller than `e` (Euler's number). I assigned `toe_cap` a value greater than `e` so that the loop is run at least 1 time.

There is no problem with this because the `toe_cap` value isn't used in any calculations and is only reassigned in the end of the loop. It's purpose here is to be used to have a correct exit statement.

If there is any possibility that the `toe_cap` value will never go below `e`, then you would have to add a different exit statement, probably according to the number of loops that you think will be enough.